# Gradle multiproject merge config files on build

Tags: java, scala, gradle

I have a gradle project (scala) with inner structure like this:

```
app
|-reference.conf
lib1
|  |- reference.conf
lib2
   |-reference.conf
   lib3
      |- reference.conf
```

My goal is to build fat jar with all these configs included, from bottom to top level. They all lie in the classpath root, so applying default merge strategies from gradle will save only first one. Is where a plugin to achieve that, or maybe any ideas how to write such plugin? Searching gives me variants with just appending all content to one file, but I need somehow to preserve applying order, lowest level libs should go first. Any ideas how to achieve that? default [merge strategies](https://docs.gradle.org/8.4/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/DuplicatesStrategy.html#INCLUDE) have no content merge policies included. Renaming files by extension can also fit, but then I need to sort them somehow before reading.
I want all files by mask **/*.conf merged into one, and all the rest should be added as is.

Comment: Perhaps indicate the desired end state?  You want all the files, but you don't want them merged into one.  If you want all the files, then you'll will need to either have varying filenames or something else.  If you indicate what you would prefer your end jar to look like, it would be easier to suggest a solution.

Comment: I need a kind of partial merge, when all conf files are merged, but other files are copied without merge